# Why won't this ruby regex match this string?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
x = "output/file.zip"

x =~ /output\/.\../
```

returns nil. There is something wrong with escaping the period, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can use [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/) for testing your regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` usually means "any character" in regex. Try `.*`, which means "`.` repeated zero or more times":

```
x =~ /output\/.*\..*/
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: You can also use `.+` which means "`.` repeated one or more times"